# How to calculate LTE KPIs from raw feed?

Tags: sql, database, telecommunication, lte, kpi

I got an assigment to take the [format of the raw Diameter feed](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qnwmr67QkmhYT-pYHtAyM4vF-bujvMob7WpRvYT5pVY/edit?usp=sharing) and decide what columns we need in order to calculate the KPIs with SQL queries.
I couldnt find any column in the feed from the KPIs formula so I started researching, how does the whole process work, but Im still not able to come up with the solution:

I.E: [Here](http://www.arib.or.jp/IMT-2000/V720Mar09/5_Appendix/Rel8/29/29272-811.pdf) , page 29, I read that the Update Location Request is indicated by comand-code set to 316 in Header, but I cant figure out what column is the header. OR can this information be encoded in the Status Bytes columns (SBx)?

Any help or other documentation to study is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by KPIs? If you're looking to find out what columns to use, wouldn't this be a question for whoever provides the feed (as it's a "business" question and not a "technical" question)? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What tool are you using to collecting the Diameter signaling?

Comment: you need counter documentation, KPI definition and then compute it by dumping it into some database or using streaming tools.